# Почему один код работает по-другому относительно другого?

Tags: python, list, циклы, переменные, перебор

**Напишите программу, которая считывает три числа и подсчитывает сумму
только положительных чисел.**

Написал такой код:

```
nums = [-31, -11, 5]
for i in nums:
    if i < 0:
        nums.remove(i)
print(sum(nums))
```

На выходе получаю **-6**, однако должен получать **5**.
Если посмотреть итоговый список, то он получается:

```
[-11, 5]
```

Не могу понять, почему остаётся -11, когда в переборе значений условием указано убирать отрицательные числа из списка? Почему это работает только для первого значения изначального списка?

Если попробовать код изменить на такой, то все получится адекватно:

```
a, b, c = -31, -11, 5
result = 0
if a > 0:
    result += a
if b > 0:
    result += b
if c > 0:
    result += c
if a and b and c < 0:
    print(0)
print(result)
```

Вывод:

```
5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому, что удаляя элементы из списка в прямой последовательности, вы "перескакиваете" через следующий элемент. Чтобы получить правильный результат, можно обойти список в обратной последовательности, например:

```
nums = [-31, -11, 5]
for i in range(len(nums) - 1, -1, -1):
    if nums[i] < 0:
        nums.remove(nums[i])
print(sum(nums)) #5
```

Другое простейшее решение:

```
print(sum(i for i in nums if i > 0)) #5
```

Comment: Спасибо! Вы не только ответили на мой вопрос, но и помогли решить. Я благодарен. Про перескакивание не знал вовсе, впредь буду знать.

Comment: Удаление из списка при итерировании по нему же - вредный совет.

Comment: Roman, согласен, но таких советов я не давал - это было условие задачи, я исправил код. Скажу больше, использование `remove` для этого вообще никуда не годится. Вы можете описать все недостатки такого подхода и разместить свой вариант решения

Comment: Не упоминать, что удалять в цикле это плохо, и давать совет, как получить правильный результат  используя все тот же неправильный подход - это поощрение этого неправильного подхода (в данном случае нашли, как обойти, но в другом можно напороться на неприятности, хорошо если при тестировании, а не в проде), а потому я остаюсь при своем мнении - совет вредный.

Answer (score 2):

Вы редактируете список, пока идёте по ниму в for, из за чего программа пропускает второе значение. Решить можно 3мя способами:

1й и самый протой - ввести переменную - итоговую сумму

```
nums = [-31, -11, 5]
sum = 0
for i in nums:
    if i > 0:
        sum += i
print(sum)
```

2й - итерироваться не по самому списку, а по его копии (в данном примере она создаётся с помощью nums[:])

```
nums = [-31, -11, 5]
for i in nums[:]:
    if i < 0:
        nums.remove(i)
print(sum(nums))
```

3й - Создать новый список и добавлять туда только положительные числа

```
nums = [-31, -11, 5]
positive_nums = []
for i in nums:
    if i > 0:
        positive_nums.append(i)
print(sum(positive_nums))

# Укороченная версия
# nums = [-31, -11, 5]
# print(sum([i for i in nums if i > 0]))
```

Comment: Спасибо, это также помогло мне в решении! Спасибо за вариативность решений!